# Factorising Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, integration-by-parts

I've been integrating by parts and I would like to factor out terms on the RHS so the integral becomes the same as the LHS.
\begin{align}
\text{RHS} &= -\int_0^5 (5t^2 -\frac{300e^{-0.7t}}{49})(-4\pi^2 f^2 n^2 \cos(2\pi nft)) \,\mathrm{d}x \\
\text{LHS} &=\int_0^5 (e^{-0.7t})(\cos(2\pi nft)) \,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}

I've tried but have had no success as I'm not quite sure what I'm allowed to do in this situation. I've left out a large portion of the RHS, just interested in factoring this particular section.

Comment: What is $f$ ? A number or a function ?

Comment: I think that $f$ is supposed to denote a frequency. Perhaps $\nu$ would be more appropriate. Also, the variable of integration $x$ doesn't match the variable in the integrand.

Comment: I know this is just a portion of the RHS, I've left a large amount out. Just wanted to know if I can factor from this particular section.